# Which Spanish scholastic economist said that economies could not be controlled even if one could track every transaction?

Tags: reference-request, history-economic-thought, history, keynesian-economics, philosophy-of-economics

Which [Spanish scholastic economist](https://mises.org/library/spanish-scholastics) said that economies could not be controlled even if one could track every transaction?

I think the context was an argument against Keynesian economics, [Cartesian mechanism](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/10100a.htm), and/or [Newtonian determinism](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04756c.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Huerta de Soto, Jesús](https://www.jesushuertadesoto.com/articles/articles-in-english/juan-de-mariana-and-the-spanish-scholastics/). “[Biography of Juan de Mariana: The Influence of the Spanish Scholastics (1536-1624)](https://mises.org/library/biography-juan-de-mariana-influence-spanish-scholastics-1536-1624).” Article. *Mises Institute* (blog), August 1, 2007:

> the Jesuit Cardinal **Juan de Lugo**, wondering what the price of equilibrium was, as early as 1643 reached the conclusion that **the equilibrium depended on such a large number of specific circumstances that only God was able to know it** ("*Pretium iustum mathematicum licet soli Deo notum*").<sup>9</sup> Another Jesuit, **Juan de Salas**, referring to the possibilities of knowing specific market information, reached the very Hayekian conclusion that it was so complex that "*quas exacte comprehendere et ponderare Dei est non hominum*" (**only God, not men, can understand it exactly**).<sup>10</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>9. Juan de Lugo (1583 1660), *Disputationes de iustitia et iure* (Lyon, 1642), vol. 2, d. 26, s. 4, n. 40, p. 312.
> 10. Juan de Salas, *Commentarii in secundam secundae D. Thomae de contractibus* (Lyon, 1617), vol. 4, no. 6, p. 9.</sup>

Comment: Your answer is out of sync with your question :(
You ask about controlling economies, but then talk about whether an equilibrium is calculable; you write the context may have been against Keynesian economics and Newtonian determinism, but then cite a source that predates both of these.

Comment: @Giskard What came to be called Newtonian determinism predates Newton.

Comment: Interesting! What about the other stuff though?